# "Cannot open include file" when implementing library that implements GLM using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, glm-math

I'm creating a game using opengl, glfw and glm. Now I have two projects, the engine (named `Cheetah`) and the game. The engine is a dll library and the game implements that library. Both the engine and the game projects contain a CMakeLists.txt, and there is one top level CMakeLists.txt that builds both.
The folder structure is as below:

[image: folder structure of project]

**The issue**

I'm trying to add glm to the library, but now I'm running in to the issue that I can build my library but I'm unable to build the game project that implements the library, throwing the compile error:

> Error C1083   Cannot open include file: 'glm/common.hpp': No such file
>   or
>   directory C:\Projects\Game\out\build\x64-Debug\Game   C:\Projects\Game\Cheetah\src\Engine\Renderer\OrthoGraphicCamera.h

Here are the CMake files per project:

**Cheetah(Engine project)**

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for Cheetah, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project ("Cheetah")

# Platform defines
IF (WIN32)
  add_compile_definitions(CH_PLATFORM_WINDOWS)
ELSE()
  # set stuff for other systems
ENDIF()

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD CHEETAH LIBRARY
#----------------------------------------------
message(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
# Define Cheetah variables
set(LIB_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies")
set(INCLUDES_DIR_PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes")
set(INCLUDES_DIR_PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
set(ENGINE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Engine")
set(ENGINE_CORE_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Core")
set(ENGINE_INPUT_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Input")
set(ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Events")
set(ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Renderer")
set(ENGINE_DEBUG_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Debug")
set(ENGINE_MATH_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Math")
set(ENGINE_RESOURCES_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Resources")
set(PLATFORM_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Platform")
set(PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR "${PLATFORM_DIR}/Windows")
set(PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR "${PLATFORM_DIR}/OpenGL")

# Set default files
list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES    
    "${ENGINE_DIR}/Engine.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Application.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Application.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Core.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/EntryPoint.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Window.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/UpdateLayer.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/UpdateLayer.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/UpdateLayerQueue.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/UpdateLayerQueue.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Time.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Time.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/RenderAction.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/RenderAction.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/GraphicsContext.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/GraphicsContext.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/RenderAPI.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/RenderAPI.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Renderer.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Renderer.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Renderer2D.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Renderer2D.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/IndexBuffer.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/IndexBuffer.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexBuffer.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexBuffer.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexArray.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexArray.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Shader.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Shader.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexBufferLayout.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexBufferLayout.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Texture.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Texture.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/OrthoGraphicCamera.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/OrthoGraphicCamera.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Renderer2DQueue.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Renderer2DQueue.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_INPUT_DIR}/Input.h"
    "${ENGINE_INPUT_DIR}/Input.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/ApplicationEvents.h"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/ApplicationEvents.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/Event.h"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/Event.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/EventDispatcher.h"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/EventDispatcher.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/EventTypes.h"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/InputEvents.h"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/InputEvents.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RESOURCES_DIR}/ResourceCache.h"
    "${ENGINE_RESOURCES_DIR}/ResourceCache.inl"
    "${ENGINE_RESOURCES_DIR}/ResourceLoader.h"
    "${ENGINE_RESOURCES_DIR}/ResourceLoader.cpp"
)
# Set platform specific files
# Windows
list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES_WINDOWS
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsWindow.h"
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsWindow.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsTime.h"
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsTime.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsInput.h"
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsInput.cpp"
)

# OpenGL
list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES_OPENGL
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLRenderAPI.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLRenderAPI.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLGraphicsContext.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLGraphicsContext.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLVertexBuffer.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLVertexBuffer.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLIndexBuffer.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLIndexBuffer.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLShader.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLShader.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLVertexArray.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLVertexArray.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLTexture.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLTexture.cpp"
)

list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES_OPENGL})

# Append Platform specific files
# Operating platform
IF (WIN32)
  list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES_WINDOWS})
  # TODO: Linux
  # TODO: MacOS
  # TODO: Android
  # TODO: IOS
ENDIF()

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_library(Cheetah SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories (Cheetah INTERFACE ${INCLUDES_DIR_PUBLIC})
target_include_directories (Cheetah PRIVATE ${ENGINE_DIR})
target_include_directories (Cheetah PRIVATE ${INCLUDES_DIR_PRIVATE})

# Add compile definitions
list(APPEND CHEETAH_COMP_DEFS
    "CH_BUILD_DLL"
    ${RENDER_API}
)

target_compile_definitions(Cheetah PRIVATE ${CHEETAH_COMP_DEFS})
target_compile_definitions(Cheetah PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:DEBUG>")
target_compile_definitions(Cheetah PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:CH_ASSERT_ENABLED>")

set_target_properties(Cheetah PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
# Copy dll to game project build folder

IF(${APPLICATION_NAME})
message("---------------------------------------------------------------------")
add_custom_command(
    TARGET Cheetah 
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Cheetah.dll"
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}"
)
ENDIF()

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD OPENGL LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
#----------------------------------------------
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Cheetah ${OpenGL})

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD GLFW LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
#----------------------------------------------
set(GLFW_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glfw")
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW example programs")
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW test programs")
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW documentation")
set(GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Generate installation target")
add_subdirectory("${GLFW_DIR}")
target_include_directories(Cheetah PRIVATE "${GLFW_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(Cheetah "glfw" "${GLFW_LIBRARIES}")
target_compile_definitions(Cheetah PRIVATE "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE")

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD GLAD LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
#----------------------------------------------
set(GLAD_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glad")
add_library("glad" "${GLAD_DIR}/src/glad.c")
target_include_directories("glad" PRIVATE "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(Cheetah PUBLIC "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(Cheetah "glad" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD STB_IMAGE LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
#----------------------------------------------
set(STB_IMAGE_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/stb_image")
add_library("stb_image" "${STB_IMAGE_DIR}/stb_image.cpp")
target_include_directories("stb_image" PRIVATE "${STB_IMAGE_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(Cheetah PUBLIC "${STB_IMAGE_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(Cheetah "stb_image" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")

#---------------------------------------------
# ADD GLM LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
# --------------------------------------------
set(GLM_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glm")
add_subdirectory("${LIB_DIR}/glm")
target_include_directories(Cheetah PRIVATE "${GLM_DIR}/glm")
target_link_libraries(Cheetah glm)
```

**Game**

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for Cheetah, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)

set(SOURCE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Game/src")

list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES 
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Main.cpp"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameLayer.cpp"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameLayer.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameObject.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameObject.cpp"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Scene.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Scene.cpp"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameScene.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameScene.cpp"
)

# Platform defines
IF (WIN32)
  add_compile_definitions(CH_PLATFORM_WINDOWS)
ELSE()
  # set stuff for other systems
ENDIF()

find_library( CHEETAH_LIB 
    NAMES Cheetah
    HINTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Cheetah")

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (Game ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories(Game PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Cheetah/includes")

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.

target_link_libraries(Game ${CHEETAH_LIB})
```

**Top level CMakeList**

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("Game")

set(APPLICATION_NAME "Game")
set(RENDER_API "OPENGL")

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory("Cheetah")
add_subdirectory ("Game")
```

Anything that could point me in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: Is the file path `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glm/glm/common.hpp` valid? This is what you are including (`${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glm/glm`) for the `Cheetah` target at the bottom of the Cheetah CMake file.

Comment: Yes, the file is valid, even if the build fails I am able to click on the include path to open that specific file.

Comment: You could consider adding the GLM include directories to your `Game` target; they don't appear to be listed there. You could also change the `Game` CMake file to simply use the `Cheetah` CMake target, instead of using `find_library()`, but that is a design decision.

Comment: @squareskittles Thanks for the suggestion, using the Cheetah CMake target solved it for me.Though I am not sure what the difference would be

Comment: I wrote up an answer to explain the advantages of using the already-created `Cheetah` CMake target. The only pitfall is that now the `Game` CMake file cannot be a stand-alone project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include directories you specify for the `Game` target is a pretty short list, compared to what you specify for `Cheetah`:

```
target_include_directories(Game PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Cheetah/includes")
```

It seems like you may need some of these `Cheetah` include directories for `Game` as well.

Note: If you are willing to re-organize the design of these two projects to always use the *top-level* CMake file, there is no need to use `find_library()` to find the `Cheetah` library. CMake already **knows** about the `Cheetah` target, as it was just created! The `Game` CMakeLists.txt file could look like this:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for Game, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)

set(SOURCE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Game/src")

list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES 
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Main.cpp"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameLayer.cpp"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameLayer.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameObject.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameObject.cpp"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Scene.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Scene.cpp"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameScene.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameScene.cpp"
)

# Platform defines
# Note, this block can also be removed if target_compile_definitions 
#  is used for Cheetah instead.
IF (WIN32)
  add_compile_definitions(CH_PLATFORM_WINDOWS)
ELSE()
  # set stuff for other systems
ENDIF()

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (Game ${SOURCE_FILES})

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.

target_link_libraries(Game PUBLIC Cheetah)
```

The Cheetah target will carry all of the include directories along with it, so there is no need to list them all separately again. It can propagate the compile definitions as well, just use [`target_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) when defining them for the `Cheetah` target.

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood the use of targets in cmake and thought they only were available in the file they are declared in.